# Applying the Fredholm alternative to prove the existence of a solution to an elliptic PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

For a uniformly strictly elliptic 2nd order differential operator $L$ defined by
\begin{equation}
Lu=-\sum_{i,j=1}^n D_j(a^{ij}D_iu)+\sum_{i=1}^nb^iD_iu+cu, 
\end{equation}
the Fredholm alternative tells us that if $a^{ij},c\in L^\infty(\Omega)$ and $b^i\in C^1(\bar\Omega)$, then a unique solution $u\in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ exists to the boundary value problem
\begin{equation}
(*)\begin{cases}
Lu=f~~~~~\mathrm{in}~\Omega \\
u=0~~~~~~~~\mathrm{on}~\partial\Omega \\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

if and only if the only solution of the equivalent homogeneous problem ($f=0$) is the trivial solution $u=0$, or equivalently if and only if $f$ is orthogonal to all solutions of the homogeneous adjoint problem.

I have been presented with this theorem but no examples in applying it, and in particular I am trying to show the existence of a unique solution to the problem $(*)$ in the case that our uniformly strictly elliptic operator is given by
\begin{equation}
Lu=-\sum_{i,j=1}^n D_j[(a^2+1)D_iu]+\sum_{i=1}^nD_iu+u, 
\end{equation}
where $a\in L^\infty(\Omega)$.

It seems to me that showing the uniqueness of a trival solution to the homogeneous problem, or showing that $f$ is orthogonal to all solutions of the homogeneous adjoint problem (how do you even find these?) is just as difficult as showing there is a solution to $(*)$ in the first place! How does one go about actually applying Fredholm's alternative in such cases? Thanks

Edit: one of the comments (and reading a couple of sources) suggests applying a maximum principle to the homogeneous problem - but in what sense can I apply a maximum principle to a weak solution?

Comment: Uniqueness of the solution $u = 0$ to the homogeneous problem should follow from the maximum principle.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I am only familiar with maximum principles for solutions in $C^2(\Omega)$ (my reference text is Evans, and as far as I'm aware there is nothing on maximum principles for weak solutions in there). Could you please be more explicit?

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at the Theorem as stated in [Evans PDEs](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/%7Exushijie/pdf/textbooks/pde-evans.pdf) (or at any other lecture notes online [[2]](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/REU2015/REUPapers/Rouse.pdf) [[3]](https://www.imperial.ac.uk/people/g.holzegel/document/5261/week6/?week6.pdf) ), you will find that you **do not get uniqueness** from the Fredholm Alternative without further insight.

However, in [Stuart & Pavliotis: Homogenization Methods](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387738284), Example 7.12 they state that the solution $u$ is unique for a satisfied (usually) second case of the Fredholm Alternative for an elliptic *periodic* differential operator.
Any idea why that is?